# Gstreamer missing Decoder meta/x-gst-fourcc-mebx

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer, libav, decoder

I'm currently working with GStreamer in a Linux environment and encountered an issue after upgrading from GStreamer 1.18 to 1.22. While trying to process a video file, I received the following error message:

```
[hevc @ 0x7f26101eba00] Skipping NAL unit 62 
[hevc @ 0x7f26100fcd40] Skipping NAL unit 62 
[hevc @ 0x7f2610113e00] Skipping NAL unit 62 
missing-plugin, type=(string)decoder, detail=(GstCaps)meta/x-gst-fourcc-mebx, name=(string)"meta/x-gst-fourcc-mebx\ decoder";
```

Also discoverer gives
`Missing plugins (gstreamer|1.0|gst-discoverer-1.0|meta/x-gst-fourcc-mebx decoder|decoder-meta/x-gst-fourcc-mebx)`

Source video is with .MOV video(made by iPhone) with I420_10LE format and not corrupted.
Also it's data (streams):

```
 Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main 10) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p10le(tv, bt2020nc/bt2020/arib-std-b67), 1920x1080, 8455 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 600 tbn, 600 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2022-02-12T07:53:40.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : HEVC
    Side data:
      DOVI configuration record: version: 1.0, profile: 8, level: 4, rpu flag: 1, el flag: 0, bl flag: 1, compatibility id: 4
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
  Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 181 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-02-12T07:53:40.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:2(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-02-12T07:53:40.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
  Stream #0:3(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-02-12T07:53:40.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
  Stream #0:4(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 34 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-02-12T07:53:40.000000Z
```

This suggests that a GStreamer plugin with a decoder for the MIME type meta/x-gst-fourcc-mebx is missing from my environment. I didn't face this issue with version 1.18, but it started occurring after the upgrade to 1.22.
I've tried searching for information about this specific decoder, but I haven't been able to find any relevant details.
Could you please provide any insights or guidance on how to handle this MIME type, or which plugin should be installed to provide the necessary decoder? If this decoder is part of a proprietary plugin or requires a specific setup, any information on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your time and help!